# How to keep a CSS 'tool-tip' div from going off screen to the right

Tags: html, css, hidden

I am writing an ASP 'document server' to list (details and icons, like in Windows Explorer) and display current and historical documents in a database.
I found a great looking CSS 'tool tip', but while displaying a list of icons, if one at the right side of the screen is hovered, the div goes off the screen to the right, like this:
[image]
Example of CSS tool tip displaying off screen
otherwise, it works absolutely flawlessly, and I really like it.

By the way... I am not using any react code or media queries.

Here is CSS code, slightly modified from the original post I found.

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.tip {
    position: relative;
}
a.tip div {
    display: none;
}
a.tip:hover div {
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: auto;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #f8f8f8),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #cccccc);
}
```

and this is the ASP code used to generate the entire icon:

```ASP
    <div class="clist2" style="display:inline-block; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; margin:3px; border-radius:10px; cursor:pointer; background-color:lightblue; color:black;"
            onMouseOver="savColor=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#E0FFFF';"
            onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor=savColor;" onClick="<%=link%>">
        <a href="#"<%=iif(len(rsd("Description")&"")=0,""," class=""tip""")%>>
            <img style="border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px; margin:5px;"
                src="<%=iif(len(""&rsd("Icon"))>0,"/Documents/"&rsd("dtPath")&rsd("Icon"),"/Images/Icons/"&iif(len(""&rsd("dtDefIcon"))>0,rsd("dtDefIcon"),"_document_.png"))%>" />
            <div><%=rsd("Description")%></div>
        </a>
        <br>
<%
                if rsd("dtPub") = "Y" or rsd("dtBook") = "Y" then
                    if len(rsd("Volume") & "") > 0 and len(rsd("Issue") & "") > 0 then
                        if rsd("Volume") > 0 and rsd("Issue") > 0 then
%>
        Vol <%=iif(rsd("Volume")>0,rsd("Volume"),"---")%>, Issue <%=iif(rsd("Issue")>0,rsd("Issue"),"---")%><br />
<%
                        end if
                    end if
%>
        <%=iif(rsd("Year")>1,rsd("MonthName")&"&nbsp;"&rsd("Year"),"")%>
<%
                else    'if rsd("dtAlbum") = "Y" then
%>
        <%=rsd("Name")%>
<%
                end if
%>
    </div>
```

Most of this ASP code is irrelevant, but I'm presenting it in anticipation of someone asking for it. The CSS class is applied to the  tag above, and the tool tip text is in the div under the img tag.

I have no idea what to try. CSS is not my forte'. I think I could turn the `left:50px` into a `right:` somehow perhaps using a `max()` function, but I've no idea how. My ideal solution would be to put the div at `left:50px`, as it's currently coded in the CSS below, UNLESS the right side if pushed off the screen, in which case the right side of the div should sit AT the right side of the screen, taking the left side of the div enough left for it to fit. But this is WAAAY above my paygrade lol, and I've no idea how to code it. Any help appreciated...

Comment: This tends to get quite complicated. Consider a battle-tested library; https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/ is almost an industry standard at this point.

Comment: Browser support for CSS Anchoring is nearly non-existent right now, but for anyone finding this in the future, this might be a viable solution: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/tether-elements-to-each-other-with-css-anchor-positioning/

Comment: I was really hoping for a css solution. Not looking forward to learning yet another new library and getting it to work. thx @MisterJojo for prettying up my question =)

Comment: Think about, if you fix it **to the right**. You will have trouble again with **to the left** of the screen. In a Javascript-less solution. 

Comment: You are correct  But if a conditional `min` or `max` was used in conjunction with the `right:`, it'd most likely work. I just don't know the configuration. thx..